# How to search with pagination in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to do a simple search with pagination in codeigniter...

I dont really know how to do it..

### My Model

```
public function testSearch()
{
    $this->db->like('Profile_for', 'Myself');
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->result();
}
```

### My Controller

```
public function searcher()
{
  $config['base_url']='http://localhost/index.php/controller/searcher';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Model->testSearch()->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;   

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['records'] = $this->Model->testSearch($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->load->view('pagination', $data);
}
```

I THINK MY CONTROLLER CODES ARE WRONG....

Please help me guyz....

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 2):

> 1.Open routes.php under Config folder

[image]

> 2.Now create a file called pagination.php under controllers folder and paste the following code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pagination extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();

        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->model("Countries_Model");
        $this->load->library("pagination");
    }

    public function index() {
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "pagination";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->Countries_Model->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 10;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 2;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(2))? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
        $data["results"] = $this->Countries_Model
            ->get_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view("pagination", $data);
    }
}
```

> 3.Create a file called countries_model.php under models folder and paste the following code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Countries_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function record_count() {
        return $this->db->count_all("tblcountries");
    }

    public function get_countries($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get("tblcountries");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
   }
}
```

> 4.Lastly, create a file called pagination.php under views folder and paste the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pagination with CodeIgniter</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Page Navigation in PHP</h1>
    <table width="400" border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td width="100" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><p>Country ID</p></td>
            <td width="300" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Country</td>
        </tr>
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Countries</h1>
            <div id="body">

        <?php
        foreach($results as $data) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $data->CountryID ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data->Country ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <div style="text-align:center"><?php echo $links; ?></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> This is code concept is same as your code.I hope this will help you
>   lot Thank you

Comment: Sir, when i press link 2, the page is loading properly but in addressbar the link number is 3 instead of 2... What to do ??

Comment: Please help.... Why am i getting page 3 in address bar when i clicked on page 2 ??

Comment: Sorry for delay but Your problem is solved or not ??